# Hsqldb - memory overuse?

Tags: java, hsqldb, h2

I am using hsqldb 2.3.2 in server memory mode.
I am experiencing a situation where I insert some information to hsqldb and the heap space used (even after GC) by HSQLDB is about 3 to 4 larger than if I kept it in a plain HashMap/LinkedList in java heap.

Here is code that inserts multiple records into a in-memory hsqldb server:

```
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost","sa","");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("set database sql syntax ora true");
    ps.execute();
    ps.close();

    ps = c.prepareStatement("create table t (x long)");
    ps.execute();
    ps.close();
    c.close();
    String x = "insert into t values(?)";
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost","sa","");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    ps = c.prepareStatement(x);
    for(int i=0;i<1000*1000*10000;i++){
        long z = new Random().nextLong();
        ps.setLong(1, z);
        ps.addBatch(); 
            if(i%1000==0){
            ps.executeBatch();
       ps.clearParameters();
       ps.clearBatch();
       ps.close();
       ps = null;
       ps = c.prepareStatement(x);
       }
       c.commit();
           c.close();           
       if(i%100000 == 0){
         System.out.println(i);//print number of rows inserted
             c.commit();
         c.close();
         c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost","sa","");
     c.setAutoCommit(false);
     ps = c.prepareStatement(x);
       }
     }
```

I track the server HSQLDB process using JVisutalVM and 
I run the code above up until a OutOfMemory occurrs

I tried different heap sizes & I stopped the code above - what is disturbing is I always see that I have inserted about 13,800,000 rows - in server with 3GB available heap - and the heap is full after terminating the code above and performing GC 0 the heap takes 2500MB -

which means that every row takes up about 180 bytes - a single long takes 8 bytes - so that is 22 time more heavier.

This is of course only a test and real tables don't usually have only one field - but the reason I explored this was that when I try to copy 1GB of memory from oracle to HSQLDB - in HSQLDB it ends up holding 4GB! (The table structure is identical)

Now, the questions:

1. What is going on? Does my test seem correct?
2. How can I reduce memory consumption in HSQLDB?
3. If there is no easy way, what other similar products may have reasonable memory usage? How is H2 in this context?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I chose H2 which has takes up about 1.2 of the original size (in my case). And it also has additional compression-in-memory modes.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a proper use case for a relational database. You have a table with only one column and are storing some long (BIGINT) values. You do not even have a primary key on this to allow you to search for the values you have inserted.

This usage does not require even a HashMap. Just use a HashSet implementation from any library.

Comment: Like I wrote - I have an actual case, with real indexed tables - and it takes 4 to 5 times longer.

The long field example was just proof.

At the end I chose H2 which has takes up about 1.2 of the original size (in my case). And it also has additional compression-in-memory modes.